# CosmosDB query runs extremely fast, but same query in Pyspark SQL takes ages

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm running a query like:

```sql
SELECT c.Name, count(c.Enabled) as Redeemed
FROM c
WHERE NOT IS_NULL(c.Enabled)
AND c.Name NOT IN ('EXAMPLE1', 'EXAMPLE2')
GROUP BY c.Name
```

on a cosmos DB table (using spark.cosmos.read with a customQuery) with 50mil records and it returns one row in 0.05 seconds. The same query run on a massive Pyspark cluster takes over an hour on the action `if not df.rdd.isEmpty()` after executing the query.

Is this just the nature of pyspark, or am I doing the query in an inefficient way? Should I instead use no custom query, and instead filter the dataframe?

Edit: I'm not totally sure why, but adding the partitioning strategy of Restrictive to the query options made this go down to a few seconds.

Comment: Welcome! It would be helpful to know more details about what you're running in pyspark. For instance: are you querying Cosmos DB via the spark connector? Or is this data somewhere else like a data lake? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"after executing the query"_? Also, how did you create `df`? Is this `df = spark.sql(...)` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add `"spark.cosmos.partitioning.strategy": "Restrictive"` to the query options, which for some reason apparently works well when returning small datasets, even when querying large datasets. Doing this made it go from over an hour to a few seconds.